# How to add font styles to org-capture templates?

Tags: org-mode, customize, org-capture

I want to change the color and font style in my template.
I use `custom-set-variable` and cannot set, for example, *italic* style

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-capture-templates
   (backquote
    (("d"
      "diary"
      entry
      (file+olp+datetree ,(concat org-directory "diary.org"))
      ,(propertize "* [%<%H:%M>] test %?" (quote face) (quote italic)))))))
```

My goal is to get this: ** [20:32] test*
Org-capture works, but the font is not italic: * [20:32] test

**UPD** I missed an important part of my question. I need to change the styles just for the time mark. Is it possible to color this time mark as a timestamp?
[image]

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to italicize the time stamp, or color it, or both?

Comment: I want both color and italics

Comment: Just in the capture template, or do you want the formatting to be permanent in your org file?

Comment: Only for this “diary” template

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that org-mode is only using the actual text of your template, and ignores the text properties. Properties are generally used for short-term formatting. Even if you add the italics property to your capture template, it won't persist between Emacs sessions.

org-mode does provide support for markup though, and that is persistent. The markup for italics is to wrap your text in `/` characters:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-capture-templates
   (backquote
    (("d"
      "diary"
      entry
      (file+olp+datetree ,(concat org-directory "diary.org"))
      "* /[%<%H:%M>] test/ %?")))))
```

If you want to *all* of your org headlines (in capture buffers and elsewhere) to appear in italics, you can accomplish this by customizing the faces for headlines: `M-x customize-face org-level-4` (and other numbers for headings of different levels).

Comment: Sorry, I missed an important part of my question. I need to stylize only part of the headline.
I updated the question

Comment: so move the second `/` to just after the timestamp